# Swiper.js, multiple swipers with multiple controls on one page

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

For my Swiper design, I need a new set of controls on each slide, so the controls visually slide away with the slide content itself. Normally, this is no problem.

But as soon as I add multiple `swipers` on one page and init them using an `each` function, none of the controls work anymore. Does anyone know how I can have multiple `swipers` with multiple sets of controls on one page?

Here is my code so far:

```js
$('.swiper-container').each(function() {
  var next = $(this).find('.swiper-next');
  var prev = $(this).find('.swiper-prev');
  
  var swiper = new Swiper($(this)[0], {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: next,
      prevEl: prev,
    },
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.swiper-container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.swiper-slide {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  height: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
.swiper-controls {
  display: flex;
}
.swiper-controls > div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- embed css -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- swiper #01 -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- slide #01-01 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-01</p>
      <div class="swiper-controls">
        <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
        <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #01-02 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-02</p>
      <div class="swiper-controls">
        <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
        <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #01-03 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-03</p>
      <div class="swiper-controls">
        <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
        <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- swiper #02 -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- slide #02-01 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-01</p>
      <div class="swiper-controls">
        <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
        <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #02-02 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-02</p>
      <div class="swiper-controls">
        <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
        <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #02-03 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-03</p>
      <div class="swiper-controls">
        <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
        <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- embed js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## 1. For next and previous arrow

You can't have multiple `swiper-controls`, one in each `swiper-slide`. You can have only one `swiper-controls` for each group of slides. As you can read on the official [doc](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#navigation), `prevEl` and `nextEl` can accept only `null | CSSSelector | HTMLElement`.

The trick  is use CSS to place that one `swiper-controls` in a way that look like it’s in each one:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-container").forEach(function (s) {
  let next = s.querySelector(".swiper-next");
  let prev = s.querySelector(".swiper-prev");

  new Swiper(s, {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: next,
      prevEl: prev
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.swiper-container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.swiper-slide {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  height: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
.swiper-controls {
  display: flex;
}
.swiper-controls > div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- embed css -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- swiper #01 -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- slide #01-01 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-01</p>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #01-02 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-02</p>

    </div>
    <!-- slide #01-03 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-03</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-controls">
    <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
    <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- swiper #02 -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- slide #02-01 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-01</p>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #02-02 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-02</p>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #02-03 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-03</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="swiper-controls">
    <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
    <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- embed js -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

## 2. For pagination bullets

However, you can have multiple paginations, those bullet points, even if it's weird because on the [doc](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#pagination), `el` has the same type as `nextEl` and `prevEl`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-container").forEach(function (s) {
  let next = s.querySelector(".swiper-next");
  let prev = s.querySelector(".swiper-prev");

  new Swiper(s, {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: next,
      prevEl: prev
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.swiper-container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.swiper-slide {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
.swiper-controls {
  display: flex;
}
.swiper-controls > div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- embed css -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- swiper #01 -->
<div class="swiper swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- slide #01-01 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-01</p>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #01-02 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-02</p>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #01-03 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #01-03</p>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-controls">
    <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
    <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- swiper #02 -->
<div class="swiper swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- slide #02-01 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-01</p>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #02-02 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-02</p>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide #02-03 -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p>slide #02-03</p>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="swiper-controls">
    <div class="swiper-prev">← previous</div>
    <div class="swiper-next">next →</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- embed js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know that normally Swiper only wants one set of controls per Swiper. In this case, the screendesign I got asks for a new set of controls on each slide and I was wondering if Swiper supports this case in any way.

Comment: The idea is use css to place that one `swiper-controls` in a way that look like it’s in each slide.

Comment: This works for controls that look like they are "fixed", but does not work if you want to let the controls slide alongside the slide content. But I guess I will have to make them static then.

Comment: However, you can have multiple paginations, you know those bullets points. See my edited code please.